# hibernet : committing transaction in current method only when transaction is not started in another method

Tags: hibernate, transactions

method 1:  starts Transaction, stores data in table C; after save i am committing data in this method.

method 2:  starts transaction; saves data in table A, saves data in table B; calls method1() so it will save data in C. now i want to commit; but problem is method1 has already committed the transaction;

method1 can also be called to just save the data in table C; so it should be saved and committed;
Please suggest how can i implement method1 so it will commit only if it has started transaction ..